# Enterprise Architect: Refering to An Instantiated Class's Attribute in a State Transition

Tags: enterprise-architect, state-machine

In Enterprise Architect, I have a class defined with an attribute which is an enum.  Is it possible to create a transition in a state machine based on a test of that enum's value?  How?

I find the only way to create transitions with triggers or signals very limited.

My intent is to export the state machine to a requirements document.  Although, I would think this should work with simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger is what causes a token to flow along a state transition. Take for example this state transition:

[image]

When you open the properties of the transition you see

[image]

Now you can add a trigger by clicking the ellipsis right to `Name:`. Here you either select an existing trigger or you create a new one on the fly.

[image]

The trigger type can be selected from the drop down:

[image]

`Signal` is the default and you can choose one from the ellipsis right to the `Specification:`. You can model the signal like this:

[image]

and you would describe in it's note that (e.g.) it fires whenever the enumeration changes.

The diagram does not show the use of the signal, but it's hidden in the connector's properties. To visualize that you could add appropriate notes and link them up to connector and elements:

[image]

Note: state machines are modeled for classes (and you usually put them inside the class). If you instantiate that class the instance will also have that state machine which can run as some kind of code inside the instance.

Comment: Would the procedure you describe be any different if I were to put the state machine inside the class definition rather than do the work on an instantiation of that class?

Comment: Actually no. If you are dong a RE you'd start with the object/instance and put the state machine therein. Later you abstract to classes. But in normal design you put the SM in the class as part of its behavioral description. And the instance just inherits that.

Comment: How would you change states when one of the classes attributes equals a certain value?  Your example is "on change of enum"; I am also interested in "enum now equals value X" behaviour.

Comment: I think I probably need to adapt my thinking to how EA works.  Rather than trying to make transitions based on class attribute values, I should probably try to make a set of signals for the class that represent changes in those values - as you have described above.

Comment: YMMV I always try to represent things in a way the current tool allows to model the most easy way. SMs are a complex thing. And OMG has just published an article (or rather a book) about SMs and how they can be modeled with UML: https://www.omg.org/spec/PSSM/About-PSSM/ good luck with that.